# Background images missing while printing a webpage

Tags: javascript, printing

I need some help on the topic: as i am printing the webpage it prints all well but not the background images, so my page breaks up at some places.Please suggest.

Regards
Jos

Comment: please provide more information this is not enough to understand your question.

Comment: what do you mean by `print`? Are you using a  physical printer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a user setting in the browser. By default some browsers won't print background images.

The user may choose to print background images also, but you can't force this with code or markup.

Comment: Not entirely true, see my answer for example.

Comment: @DavidMulder: I can't see what it is that you mean would not be true? What you are suggesting is to not use background images, but that doesn't change what's true about background images.

Comment: What you say is that you can't force it with code or markup, but the list-style-image property acts *entirely* like a background image which **is** printed (in the sense of being behind the content of the element unlike img tags which require special markup) and thus forcing those images **is** possible with some code (css).

Comment: @DavidMulder: They act like background images, but they are not background images. You are using list item images *instead of* background images. What I said about background images is still true in every sense.

Comment: Depends, they **are** background images, just not the normal type we tend to use and not intended to be used this way. True, they aren't `background-image`'s, but what the question was asking was about printing background images in general and your answer made Jos probably believe this to be entirely impossible.

Comment: @DavidMulder: So, exactly what in my answer is not correct, according to you?

Comment: Slow reply, but the fact that you are giving the impression that it's impossible to fix/solve this, which is not true. It can be both fixed on the html/markup level (as demonstrated by Theorian) and on the css level (as demonstrated by me).

Comment: @DavidMulder: What gives you that impression?

Comment: The fact that you are saying 1. this is a user setting (true, but by-passable) and 2. that you can't force it to be printed (which you can).

Comment: @DavidMulder: That's not what the answer says. Your impression of the answer is wrong, so you chose to downvote the answer, because you can't downvote your incorrect impression of it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12564/discussion-between-david-mulder-and-guffa)

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: What's wrong has been been plenty clear before. `list-style-image` is a backaground image just as `background-image` is a background image. One is printed, the other is not. This time round Chani (based on the time) got probably confused by your incorrect answer and downvoted it ;-)

Comment: @DavidMulder: You still claim that my answer is incorrect, but you still haven't given any good explanation why you think so. Would you please stop badmouthing other answers just because you didn't write them.

Comment: @DavidMulder: Well, first of all I wasn't asking you because it wasn't you who downvoted this time, so why are you sticking your nose in the conversation? Second, you are only repeating your claim that my answer is incorrect over and over, so that doesn't add anything at all to the matter. Your comments simply doesn't contribute anything.

Answer (score 3):

In  your print stylesheet you should use something along the lines of:

```
.background {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-image: url(image.gif);
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Please note that you can't use image sprites and more advanced background positioning this way and you need to do it for every image.

Comment: interesting suggestion. Too bad it can't be used with sprites.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same issue.  My header background image wasn't printing on single post articles, leaving a big white gap at the head of the page where the header image would normally show. So to fix this, I added the background image via HTML directly on the page - which your users browser will print by default.  Below is a basic example of how to achieve this:

1, Create a blank style sheet and name it print.css. Now add this style sheet to your page header, and make sure **media="print"**. We need this in order to tell the browser which elements we want and don't want to print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pathtoyour/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

2, Add the image you want printed to your page and make sure it has an **ID** so we can style it within the print.css and your main style sheet:

```
<div id="header">    
<img id="print-image" src="pathtotheimageyouwanttoprint.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

3, In your **main style sheet**, add your **image ID** so we can tell browsers to stop the image from showing during normal viewing of your page:

```
#print-image {display:none}
```

4, In your **print.css** style sheet, because we've told your image to not display in your main style sheet, we need to now make sure that your image prints and doesn't remain hidden. Add the following to achieve this:

```
#print-image {display:block;}
```

You're done. Test and adjust styling to suit.

Doing this also allows you to fully customise the way your page is printed, for example -  when printing, you now have the ability to hide your print button, menu items etc. and can code in any styling as per normal.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using David Aragon's Javascript

```
function replaceSprite(selector){

if ($.browser.msie == true) {
    var back_x = $(selector).css('background-position-x'),
        back_y = $(selector).css('background-position-y'),
        back_position = back_x+" "+back_y;
} else {
    var back_position = $(selector).css('background-position');
}

var back_image = $(selector).css('background-image'),
    width = $(selector).width(),
    height = $(selector).height(),
    index1 = back_image.indexOf('http'),
    index2 = back_image.indexOf('.png');

back_position = back_position.split(" ");
back_image = back_image.substring(index1, (index2+4));

$(selector)
        .append('<img src="'+back_image+'"/>')
    .css('width',width)
    .css('height',height)
    .css('overflow','hidden');

$(selector).find('img')
    .css('margin-left',back_position[0])
    .css('margin-top',back_position[1]);
```

}

http://quickleft.com/blog/printing-css-sprites